# Join two models when only 1 model has a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-viewsets

```
ModelA
------
id
atr_a
atr_b
atr_c
is_active
```

```
ModelB
------
id
atr_d
atr_e
modelA_id
```

Without modifying either model, I need to include `ModelB` data in my `ModelA` ViewSet.  I am not sure how this should be done given my constraints.

```
class ModelAViewSet(...):
    endpoint_permissions = [...]

    queryset = (
        ModelA.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    )
    serializer_class = ModelASerializer
    filterset_class = ModelAFilter
```

If I had the foreign key included in ModelA, it would be trivial, simplying including the `ModelB` serializer in my modelA serializer for the foreign key column, but without that, I am not sure on the approach. (Adding ModelB as a foreign key modelA is not an option)

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    atr_a = serializers.CharField()
    atr_b = serializers.CharField()
    atr_c = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        ref_name = "ModelA"
        model = ModelA
        fields = (
            "id",
            "atr_a",
            "atr_b",
            "atr_c"
        )
```

```
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    atr_d = serializers.CharField()
    atr_e = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        ref_name = "ModelB"
        model = ModelB
        fields = (
            "id",
            "atr_d",
            "atr_e"
        )
```

Wanted output

```
{
id : 1,
atr_a : "a",
atr_b : "b",
atr_c : "c",
atr_d : "d",
atr_e : "e"
}
```

Comment: With the serializer... Why is that not possible for your `ModelASerializer`?

Comment: Because `ModelA` does not have a foreign key to model b, only modelB has a foreign key to modelA, but when I return modelA, I need to return the `atr_d` and `atr_e` from modelB.

So how do I get the modelB data included into the modelAViewSet so I can include it in the `ModelASerializer`

Comment: that doesn't matter. Can you please share the current serializer together with the expected output of your view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Got it, I've added both serializers and my expected output from `ModelAViewSet` I am not sure how to get the `ModelB` data.